# How to set bitrate of IVP8Encoder filter in a DirectShow application

Tags: c++, video, directshow, webm

How to set bitrate of vp8encoder filter in directshow application (c++ code). my graph looks like this.

Webcam --->Webm VP8 encoder -->AVI mux --->file writer(.avi)

I'm able to set bitrate in graphedit by right clicking vp8encoder->properties. But i want to set bitrate using c++ code in directshow application. I'm new to directshow please provide sample code . Thanks in advance

Comment: [Beginning of the Question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/01991105-e103-438f-bfa7-725e06450c04)

Answer (score 0):

The subject suggests that you already have IVP8Encoder interface on hands (which also goes in line with the fact that you do have IDL files and their derivatives).

`IVP8Encoder::SetTargetBitrate` is the method that does the thing.

```
//Target data rate
//
//Target bandwidth to use for this stream, in kilobits per second.
//The value 0 means "use the codec default".

HRESULT SetTargetBitrate([in] int Bitrate);
HRESULT GetTargetBitrate([out] int* pBitrate);
```